# Error mapping JSON to observableArray

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

Can't load my JSON data into ko.observableArray and have no clue why.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function Region(uid, name) {
        this.uid = ko.observable(uid);
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
    }

    function CompanyViewModel() {
        this.regions = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new CompanyViewModel());   

    // Init.
    $.getJSON( '/regions/', 
        function(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok')
            {
                var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.regions, function(item) {
                    return new Region(item.uid, item.name);
                });
                CompanyViewModel.regions( mappedData );
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Debugger says: Uncaught TypeError: Object function CompanyViewModel()... has no method 'regions'

I'm new to Knockout and sure there is some obvious error, but i don't know where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but should give you an idea on what I mean, this is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Region = function(uid, name) {
        this.uid = ko.observable(uid);
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
    }

    var CompanyViewModel = function() {
        this.regions = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var model = new CompanyViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);   

    // Init.
    $.getJSON( '/regions/', 
        function(data){
            if(data.status == 'ok')
            {
                var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data.regions, function(item) {
                    return new Region(item.uid, item.name);
                });
                model.regions( mappedData );
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I hope now i understand my error. I have created "anonymous" viewmodel object and tried to invoke method from model definition itself, not from object, right?

Comment: Right, you were not working on the instance of the model. By the way, if you don't plan on changing a property (say an ID), there's no reason to make it into an observable.